# Speed of electrical NOT gate

Tags: logic-gates

How fast could a NOT gate theoretically work? Like minimal size and maximal transfer speed (I don't know if this would be lightspeed or not)? It's because I'm researching Domain-wall logic and want to compare it's minimal speed (a few picoseconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are very, very fast.In CMOS logic gates , the MOSFET's have a capacitance of a few pF
lets say the MOSFET has 10Ohm series resistance τ=RC = a few hundred ps.